# How to do update the matched array element

Tags: mongodb, meteor

user1 in database

```
{
    counts: [{code:"aaa", num:100}, {code:"bbb", num:200}]
}
```

`counts` is an Array, it has two elements `code` and `num`.

How to let `num` increase 1 if `code = "aaa"`?

```
Meteor.users.update(user1._id, {$inc: {???}}); // How to write this?
```

Thanks

Comment: As a note for meteor. Performing updates from the client (browser) without the main `_id` is considered insecure. As long as you include the `_id` as well as the element to to match in the query `{ "_id": user1._id, "counts.code": "aaa" }` then all should be fine. Anything else implies a multiple document update and is insecure, therefore should be defined as a server side method to be invoked. But the basic answer is include the element to match in the query portion of the update and reference with the positional `$` operator  `{ "$inc": { "counts.$.num": 1 }}`.in the update portion.

Comment: @BlakesSeven thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Gotta positionally match. Example:

```
Players.update({
  _id: Meteor.userId(),
  'games._id': Session.get('gameId')
}, {
  $inc: { 'games.$.score': 1 }
});
```